# finding max frequency in a balanced tree [homework]

Tags: java, tree, find

homework tasks:

In order to be able to know both how many unique words in a file
but also the number of occurrences of words you will develop a special
tree data structure. Call the class TreeSetCounter. A node in such a tree is
composed of a word and a counter. The procedures
implemented:

addWord- add words to the tree if the word does not exist. If the word
already be counter increment

Make empty () - makes the tree even

getMaxFrek () -return word which has occurred most number of times.
How can you do it most effectively?

iterator () - return an iterator to the tree. It shall be used to
print tree in alphabetical order.

Use as a starting point a balanced tree implementation.
Write a program that reads a file and print
both the words and the number of occurrence of each word.

Could anyone give me ideas of how I should implement this and which way is the fastest to traverse throughout the tree and find max?

the tree adding code:

```
/**
 * Insert into the tree.
 * @param word the item to insert.
 * @freq increment if word is already present.
 */
public void addWord(String name) {
    root = addWord(name,root);
}
/**
 * Internal method to insert into a subtree.
 * @param word the item to insert.
 * @param t the node that roots the tree.
 * @return the new root.
 * @freq increment if word is already present.
 */
protected Node addWord( String word, Node t )
{
    if( t == null )
        t = new Node( word );
    else if( word.compareTo( t.word ) < 0 )
        t.left = addWord( word, t.left );
    else if( word.compareTo( t.word ) > 0 )
        t.right = addWord( word, t.right );
    else
        t.freq++;
    return t;
}
```

the getMaxFreq that doesnt work... I get a nullPointerException

```
 private Node getMaxFreq(Node node){
    Node temp = null;
    if(node.left != null){
        if(node.compareTo(getMaxFreq(node.left)) > 0){
            temp = node;
        }
        else{
            temp = node.left;
        }
    }
    if(node.right != null){
        if(node.compareTo(getMaxFreq(node.right)) > 0){
            temp = node;
        }
        else{
            temp = node.right;
        }
    }
    return temp;

}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: If the tree is balanced after alphabetical order, the max can be anywhere in the tree, right? So how would you expect to make it any faster than O(n)? Perhaps you need a separate data structure to keep track of the frequencies.

Comment: @aioobe

im open for suggestions

Comment: This sounds like homework, and I don't know the constraints or goals of this. But what about making a priority queue implemented as [max-heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29)?

Comment: @aioobe updated the question

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to spot the flaw in your implementation of "getMaxFreq", consider the scenario of a tree with one single node, your solution would return null while the right answer should be the only node.

As one of the requirement is to return an iterator to the tree for printing tree in alphabetical order. One intuitive solution is to implement a binary search tree with the word as tree node key, for iterator implementation of binary search tree, [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2014/04/leetcode-binary-search-tree-iterator-java/) is a good guideline.

To find the word with highest frequency, [here](http://www.studyalgorithms.com/tree/find-the-maximum-element-in-a-binary-tree/) is a good example to use recursive to find the maximum element in a binary tree, in your case, the maximum element is the word with highest frequency.